# Batch File Creating Text File With Date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file to run a defrag on a computer - as below. At the moment it is creating the text file named ComputerName.txt

> @echo off
>
> defrag.exe c: -f -v >"C:\Defrag\ComputerName.txt"

How can I get the date to also ammend to the end of the text file? IE:

> ComputerName.2011.02.08.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/- " %%A in ('date /T') do set var=c:\defrag\ComputerName.%%C.%%A.%%B.txt

defrag c: -f -v > %var%